# Does AmazonMQ (rabbitmq ) has storage support(EBS/EFS)?

Tags: amazon-mq

Recently i restarted amazonmq machine, all the queues were lost.I see only the activeMQ has support for storage using EBS/EFS. is there anything am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ is durable with EBS.

"RabbitMQ brokers can be created as single-instance brokers or in a cluster deployment. For both deployment modes, Amazon MQ provides high durability by storing its data redundantly."

[RabbitMQ Broker Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/rabbitmq-broker-architecture.html)

[Console Reboot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-rebooting-broker.html)

Comment: But when i rebooted my machine all the ques were lost. is there any parameteres am i missing ? @KafKaOwn

Comment: Not sure, do you have anything in the logs?

Comment: no logs, thats why Im asking. Only activeMQ has support i guess. @KafKafOwn